# Redpark cable for arduino, any alternative

Tags: arduino, usb, ipod

I'm trying to interface my Arduino and iPod. If I use my Apple USB female connector and I buy a usb2serial cable ($5), can that combination work in place of [this Redpark cable](http://redpark.com/c2db9.html) ($59!!)?

[image]

Redpark cable

Answer (score 1):

Apple are notoriously strict on what they allow to interface with their 30-pin port. I would be surprised if a makeshift system like what you have suggested works. But I am not confident that it wouldn't.

If you are interested in interfacing with an Arduino, would you absolutely want to go to a serial connection or would you want a direct connection to the ports? If you are looking for a direct connection I would think it would be more direct to get a breakout board like the [PodBreakout from Sparkfun](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/8295).

[image: PodBreakout]

It is much cheaper than the Redpark cable and then you could directly connect only the cables you need to.